# Xero Api request limit is exceeding when returning bulk creditor invoices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xero-api

I'm trying to retrieve creditor invoices with in date range. The client got more than 26000 records in their xero system. I have used paging to retrive all the creditor invoices then tried to filter the date and this ended up in error 'exceeding the xero limit and try again later'.
Is there any efficient way or any query string method to retrieve creditor invoices for a date range?

Comment: possible answer is here in of all places...the documentation - who would have thought?  https://developer.xero.com/documentation/auth-and-limits/xero-api-limits

Comment: @JohnB thanks for the update. I have managed to do with using the query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used the query string to first filter the desired range of invoices.

```
  xeroAPI.Invoices.Where(queryString).Page(curPage).Find().Where(m => m.Type == Xero.Api.Core.Model.Types.InvoiceType.AccountsPayable)
```